# Inventory database for point of sale (any x for £x)

Tags: php, mysql, database, inventory

I'm working on an inventory / invoice system written in MySQL / PHP (possibly with some kind of Access front end as well as web interface).

The problem is that I want the inventory of products to be able to cope with items that have discounts for multiples such as "any two for £10". What I want to happen is if say 10 items are added to an invoice, it can work out if any of those items meet the "any x for £x" requirements and apply the discount. The added complication is that any item could have different multiple discounts such as "any 2 for £10" as well as "any 3 for £12". Basically like what the supermarkets do - nice an easy for the end user.

It works fine if I want any x of the SAME item entered on to the same invoice line but it needs to be more flexible than that.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this? Thanks in advance. I am pretty good with HTML / MySQL / PHP / JavaScript etc.

Answer (score 0):

Working with PHP and MySQL, you could have a "discounts" table where you save the ID for the product, the number of the products, price and name of the offer.
In this way, with a simple query, when you are calculating the final value for the invoice you check against the table if an offer for each product exists:

`SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE product_id = x AND quantity >= y`

So, in the end, you have a table for products and prices and a related table for offers.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object representing various discounts (I'll use C# syntax)

```
public interface IOrderProcessor
{
   bool CanBeApplied(OrderItem item);
   void Apply(OrderItem item);
}

public class TwoForOneProcessor : IOrderProcessor
{
   public bool CanApply(OrderItem item)
   {
      // check if the product is in 2 for 1 discount
   }

   public void Apply(OrderItem orderItem)
   {
      // apply the discount
   }
}
```

and an order processor, that will take all the discount objects and apply it to the items in order. Data for the processor can be stored in database (i.e. which product it can be applied to etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to build some kind of 'discount' table that holds basic information about the discount - such as a unique identifier and description (this could also be linked to eligibility rules required to trigger this discount - promotional code for example).

This table will also need to hold rules for creating discount bundles for your example to work, things like "number of products required to trigger the discount" and the "bundle value" - for flexibility these fields should be NULLable so that you don't *have* to use bundles; you can use individual prices determined in a 'product to discount' table.

As a basic example, you might have a discount table like:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | description | units_required | bundle_price | start_date | end_date |
+----+-------------+----------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| .. + ...         | ...            | ...          | ...        | ...      |
```

... and a product_to_discount link table like:

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| id | product_id | discount_id | units_required | unit_price |
+----+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| .. | ...        | ...         | ...            | ...        |
```

You then link products to discounts, so if you've got something like "Buy any 3 items from this range for only £10" you'll need to link the entire range of possible qualifying products to the discount and set the `units_required` to 3 - then if any 3 of those items are in the "basket" apply the `bundle_price`.

You might need to do some filtering to sort out which bundle takes precedence if there is more than one possibility (probably by calculating which gives the biggest discount).

The other possibility with a setup like this is that it allows you to do much simpler discounts as well. You can simply leave `units_required` and `bundle_price` as `NULL` and link just a single product to the discount; potentially many times with different price breaks at different `product_to_discount.units_required` values - so you can set a discount value for a single product, or a greater discount per item for larger volumes.

You could also add in a field like `product_to_discount.product_is_discount` if you wanted to do something like "Buy X, Y or Z and get Q FREE".

This is fairly vague sort of outline but I hope it helps point you in the "right" direction...

Oh, one other thing to bear in mind, if your system is doing any accounting you'll need to pass down a "discount line" to account for the discrepancies between the expected product price and the discounted one.